# class or interface expected error for service declaration in manifest file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I have tried all solution on stack but nothing worked for this problem

Manifest file

```
  <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Screen"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".LocalService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>
```

MainActivity where service is called

```
    startService(new Intent(this,LocalService.class));
```

Service class

```
     public class LocalService extends Service {
      public LocalService() {
      }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove ' in your code

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Screen"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".LocalService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>
```